# how to ELSE out the "skip"?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

here is my code:

```
IF EXIST "D:\Windows\\." IF EXIST "D:\Program Files\\." (
        IF NOT EXIST "D:\TP\\." (
            MD "D:\TP\"
            MD "D:\TP\ver 5.1\"
        )
        MOVE "app.exe" "D:\TP\ver 5.1\"
) ELSE (
SHIFT
)
IF EXIST "C:\Windows\\." IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\\." (
        IF NOT EXIST "C:\TP\\." (
            MD "C:\TP\"
            MD "C:\TP\ver 5.1\"
        )
        MOVE "app.exe" "C:\TP\ver 5.1\"
) ELSE (
SHIFT
)
IF EXIST "E:\......... for rest of available drives xD
```

what I'm trying to achieve is to skip whole commands if they are not matching my criteria. what do I do wrong?

Comment: read the output of  `shift /?` It has nothing to do with skipping anything

Comment: Your code and your understanding of what various commands do is flawed. Please state exactly what you are attempting to do. For example, do you want the app.exe to be installed on only one drive? (I suspect this is the case). Or is there a possibility it could be put in multiple locations.

Comment: @dbenham no and no. app.exe is just a reference file for another program. All I needed to achieve was "to copy them on a drve where is windows installed" and kind off failed reading wrong answers here on stackoverflow while creating my code.

Comment: why don't you use the system variable `%SystemDrive%`?

Comment: @Stephan I tried to replace all "D"s with %SystemDrive% and end my script before "IF EXIST "C:" part, but I gues its not so simple. how should I yse it?

Comment: au contraire my friend. It's even simpler. `%SystemDrive%` tells you, on which drive Windows is installed. No need to look into every drive. Just `MD "%SystemDrive%:\TP\ver 5.1\"` (creates the complete path, no need to use `md` twice) and `move "app.exe" "%systemdrive%\TPver 5.1\"`

Comment: @Stephan wow, thanks a lot, this was really helpfull!

Comment: The point about `else` is that `else` refers to the previous unclosed `if`. Batch is not capable of interpreting the layout - indeed, no language is. In your original code, there are *three* `if` statements (then 3 again). The innermost `if` (controlling the `md` commands) is closed - it has no `else` clause because the `)` after the `md`s is not immediately followed by `else`. The `else` thus applies to the *middle* `if` (program files) not to the outermost (windows) or to the cascaded `if` (windows and program files)

Comment: @Magoo so in other words if I have IF which is wrapped up in another IF then using ELSE which interacts with superior IF is impossible. I see now.

Comment: Impossible in batch? Never heard of such a thing! If you put `(` before the middle `if` and a matching `)` after the `move` statement, you get  if windows **(** if program files (if exist(md)move) **)** else  so the `else` then refers to the outermost `if`.

Comment: You should delete your very first sentence; your opinion about `else` does not contribute anything helpful to this post...

Comment: @aschipfl will you return me my +2 rep points?

Comment: For the question as it is now -- no; 1. it is not a helpful question because you just say "not working", but you do not describe what your code is supposed to do, neither do you mention what it actually does and/or what error messages appear; 2. as I said in [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567916/how-to-else-out-the-skip#comment56908397_34567916)...; by the way: how do you know it was me? or were you just guessing?

Comment: @aschipfl Probably you just couldn't understand problematics behind it. Question was answered, so enjoy your golden badge on me in name of all your victims and have a nice day^^

Comment: @JudgeDredd yes, your question was answered. With a lot of guessing. Aschipfl is right: your question isn't good. Don't take downvotes personally. It's not "Judge is a bad guy", but "this question as it's formulated is unlikely to help others"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED (thx to Henrik's comment)**

```
IF EXIST "D:\Windows\" IF EXIST "D:\Program Files\" (
        IF NOT EXIST "D:\TP\" (
            MD "D:\TP\ver 5.1\"
        )
        MOVE "app.exe" "D:\TP\ver 5.1\"
    )
IF EXIST "C:\Windows\" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\" (
        IF NOT EXIST "C:\TP\" (
            MD "C:\TP\ver 5.1\"
        )
        MOVE "app.exe" "C:\TP\ver 5.1\"
    )
```

**BUT then, witchcraft came to place (thx to Stephan's leadership) and solved this again**

```
MD "%systemdrive%\TP\ver 5.1\"
MOVE "app.exe" "%systemdrive%\TP\ver 5.1\"
```